# Exporting Google Charts with jsPDF working on Chrome, but not on Firefox (blank image in document)

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-visualization, jspdf, canvg

```
                        var doc = new jsPDF();
                        doc.setFontSize(30);
                        doc.setTextColor(244, 070, 017);
                        doc.setFont("courier");
                        doc.setFontType("normal");
                        doc.text(35, 25, '<?php echo "Accessi ".$months[$_POST['month']]." ".$_POST['year']; ?>');
                        function getImgData(chartContainer) {
                            var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
                            var svg = chartArea.innerHTML;
                            var chartDoc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
                            var canvas = chartDoc.createElement('canvas');
                            canvas.setAttribute('width', chartArea.offsetWidth);
                            canvas.setAttribute('height', chartArea.offsetHeight);


                            canvas.setAttribute(
                                'style',
                                'position: absolute; ' +
                                'top: ' + (-chartArea.offsetHeight * 2) + 'px;' +
                                'left: ' + (-chartArea.offsetWidth * 2) + 'px;');
                            chartDoc.body.appendChild(canvas);
                            canvg(canvas, svg);
                            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/JPEG');
                            doc.addImage(imgData, "JPEG", 0,30); 
                            canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
                            return imgData;
                          }

                    $( document ).ready(function() {

                        $('#pdfBtn').click(function () {   
                            var chartContainer = document.getElementById('line_div');
                            var chartDoc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
                            var img = chartDoc.createElement('img');
                            img.src = getImgData(chartContainer);
                            doc.save('grafico.pdf');
                        });

                    });
                        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
                        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                        function drawChart()
                        {
                            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                            data.addColumn('string', 'Giorni');
                            data.addColumn('number', 'Numero accessi');

                            data.addRows([
                            <?php
                            for ($i = 1; $i < $days; $i++) {
                                echo "['".$i."', ".$dati[$i]."], ";
                            }
                            echo "['".$i."', ".$dati[$i]."]";
                            ?>
                            ]);

                            var chart_div = document.getElementById('line_div');
                            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(line_div);


                            chart.draw(data, {
                                width: 780,
                                height: 340,
                                legend: 'right',
                                title: ''
                            });
                        }
                    </script>

                    <div id="line_div"></div>
                    <button id="pdfBtn">Salva PDF</button>
```

This is my Google Chart which takes data from PHP and populate the chart with the for cycle in addRows. I added a button (pdfBtn) which let me export my document created with jsPDF. Everything works with all browsers, but with Firefox I get a black image instead of the chart in the exported document. I tried to change the format to PNG, but I get a white image instead of black. I know that it relates to the background color properties of JPEG and PNG, but I tried to set CSS and nothing works. I really don't know how to solve this problem. However, pdfBtn doesn't work on Internet Explorer, but I would be really happy to firstly solve the problem on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with converting SVG by canvg library.
You should clean-up your SVG file before calling canvg.
In my case it was removing all of attributes with custom namespaces and also removing height="Infinity" from the svg element.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue with Google Charts + wkhtmltopdf by replacing:

```
<script src="http://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

by

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Somehow the wkhtmltopdf library could not handle a Google Chart html page  which contains the first javascript include.